# Mac Terminal Forgetting Aliases

Tags: macos, terminal

Every time I set a new alias in terminal and exit out it seem to forget them. Any ideas as to why that is?

I had Git installed too, but whenever I try to use it I get a command not found error.

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct shell behaviour.

Edit your `~/.profile` file and add the aliases there so they persist across sessions.

The `git` error is because your `$PATH` isn't set correctly; find where `git` is installed and  add that to your `PATH` variable, again by editing the `~/.profile` file.

Comment: It may not be `.profile`. It could also be `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`. I like to keep my bash functions inside my `.bashrc` and my aliases and path stuff inside `.bash_profile`. I also do not have a `.profile`.

Comment: @edhedges I'm sure it's `.profile`, but I'm not at my Mac at the moment.  If it doesn't exist, then substitute `.bash_profile`, as you say.

Comment: I have Mac OSX 10.6.8 and do not have `.profile`. That is why I commented.

Comment: @edhedges Doing a google for "mac .profile" shows that it appears to be the file used.

Comment: Like I said, I am just trying to help out with my personal Mac experience. That being said all three files will work for Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

- `.profile` will affect all shells for that user
- `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` will affect bash shells
- Similarly, `.csh_profile` would affect csh shells, and so on

You can also use `/etc/profile` to apply changes for all users.